# Read omni.jar archive file with MiniZip library

Tags: c, windows, firefox, archive, php-ziparchive

Firefox store its default configuration information in omni.jar (older version) or omni.ja (later versions). Both omni.jar and omni.ja just are zip file format. So we can use many programs/libraries to compress or decompress them.

I want to get some default information of Firefox. So I must read some file in those omni file. I have used 7zip program to see the content of omni or MiniZip/Zlib library to read omni in my program.

With later version, omni.ja, it is read well. But with older versions, MiniZip cannot open the omni.jar file. Then I use 7zip to open those file: omni.ja was ok, omni.jar was fail. But with some other program, ex: WinRar, WinZip, ... both omni file is opened well.

I was google and get some information: with older version, Firefox has created the omni.jar file (a zip file format) with no zip standard. blah blah. But why WinRar or WinZip can read.

Anyone can help me to get MiniZip read omni.jar file with no error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if we open a zip file with notepad, we will see that it is started with "PK". But with older Firefox omni.jar file, it is started with "ü¬".

Comment: A sad news: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple: Your "old" `omni.jar` is broken. My `omni.jar` starts with `PK`.

I suggest to download Firefox from the [official archive](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) once more.

**[EDIT]** It seems that different builds of Firefox use different tools to built the ZIP archive. The en-US version uses a ZIP-like format which doesn't start with `PK`. While in theory the file format is valid (it contains data followed by the list of entries), almost no tool really supports this format (so WinZIP and WinRAR are the exceptions).

This intention is reflected by the rename of `omni.jar` to `omni.ja`: It's not encrypted, it's just a ZIP format that isn't widely supported and the [US Firefox developers don't want to change this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605524).

The other developers (for example for the de version) use official tools to build the omni archive so those versions can be modified with any tool.

You will need to find a way to update the archive using WinZIP / WinRAR or you need to download the original firefox sources and add your patches to the build process.

Comment: I have downloaded FF from official archive. The result is same.

Comment: Why can't 7-Zip open some ZIP archives?  

In 99% of these cases it means that the archive contains incorrect headers. Other ZIP programs can open some archives with incorrect headers, since these programs just ignore errors.  

If you have such archive, please don't call the 7-Zip developers about it. Instead try to find the program that was used to create the archive and inform the developers of that program that their software is not ZIP-compatible.  

There are also some ZIP archives that were encoded with methods unsupported by 7-Zip, for example, WAVPack (WinZip).

Comment: So, Does omni.jar contain incorrect headers. Or, Does omni.jar encode with methods unsupported, WAVPack (WinZip)?

Comment: My omni.jar is from Firefox 4.0.1. Can you try on a different computer? omni.jar contains a lot of the code for Firefox so it might be a target for a computer virus. The first four bytes must be `50 4b 03 04`; I really don't understand why WinRAR and WinZip can open them. Try a file type analysis - maybe it's a different archive format and the extension is wrong.

Comment: I tested on some computers. How about your? Do it open with 7zip well? And it start with 50 4b 03 04 (or PK)? Is this FF intentional?

Comment: Yes, mine is a standard ZIP file with the normal head. Send me the URL of the version that you downloaded.

Comment: All version: ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: Which one specifically did you try? And a virus might replace the ZIP reading code in FF to make sure anti-virus tools can't decode the archive.

Comment: I tried with versions from 4 to 9 on 3 computers: 2 win7 + 1 winxp

Comment: I'm not going to try to figure out which of the 15000 versions of FF you tried.

Comment: No, it just 6 version. Where is 15000?

Comment: You can test with any version from 4 to 9.

Comment: 38. How can I encrypt/decrypt zip files with zlib?  

zlib doesn't support encryption. The original PKZIP encryption is very weak and can be broken with freely available programs. To get strong encryption, use GnuPG which already includes zlib compression. For PKZIP compatible "encryption", look at InfoZIP.

Comment: There are six platforms and 136 languages and 10 releases -> 8160 files

Comment: I think those omni.jar file were encrypted.

Comment: I have just tested with en-US version. :)

Comment: I have installed python, then get <a href="http://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhg.mozilla.org%2Fmozilla-central%2Fraw-file%2Ff7016571b472%2Fconfig%2Foptimizejars.py&ei=9c1hT7COJ6akiAfTpN3wBQ&usg=AFQjCNE8TLPb1dndfX6NbnUNqxSvF9R4hg&sig2=7BGOFagWo4I-hGdkJioe1A">optimizejars.py. - Hg - Mozilla</a> to the folder which contains omni.jar, then run optimizejars.py --deoptimize ./ ./ ./ -> open omni.jar with notepadd++, it start with PK. But, it cannot open with 7zip or MiniZip library.

Comment: Frustrating, isn't it? Have you tried to run WinZip from the command line? http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm